# How to deal with collapsing margins on html & body?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout that consists of a left menu area and right content area.  Each of the two is an iframe because I need pdf's to load into the content area only.  I have the layout resizing for browser size and exactly how I want it except a scrollbar appears on the right and I have a tiny area on the bottom.  Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
html
{
    font:100% Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
body
{
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px; 
}
#wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#menu{
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:15em;
}
#content{
    height:100%;
    margin-left:15em;
    text-align:left;
}
iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
}
```

and the HTML is fairly simple (iframe html has no styling at all):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RPWRF O&amp;M Manual</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <iframe frameborder="0" src="left.html" name="menuframe">
        </iframe></div>
    <div id="content">
        <iframe frameborder="0" src="right.html" name="contentframe">
        </iframe></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `display: block;` on the `iframe`'s. `iframe`'s are by nature inline elements and inline elements sit on the baseline of the surrounding text. The baseline allows for descenders (the tail of the 'g' etc.) and the white space is the space taken up by the descenders (even if there are none).

Setting `display: block;` gets rid of the added white space, and gets rid of your unwanted scroll bar.

Comment: OMG I had spent all day trying to figure out what the space was from and figured it was margin's collapsing and thus height's not calculated right!  This worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much.